# Resize image but keep its ratio - is it possible by means of HTML, CSS or jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

[image: table]

I have [a top script](http://preferans.de/top20.php) displaying a list of users (will turn this script into a Drupal block later), with a link to their individual profile web page. For the most of the users I have a foto in my database, which I'd love to display at the top page, but I don't know how to resize their fotos.

I.e. a user might have a 160x100 picture or a 20x40 picture, but on my top page I want the fotos to fit inside a **60x40** rectangle.

And I can't just write **<img src="..." width="60" height="40">** because the images will appear distorted then (i.e. ratio won't be preserved).

Is there a way in HTML, CSS or jQuery to scale an image, but keep its ratio?

(And I don't want to download each image by a Perl/PHP-script, then run ImageMagick or anything similar - this is too heavy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<img id="fixMe" src="something.jpg" />


jQuery(function(){
      var elm=jQuery('#fixMe');
      var allowedHeight=40;
      var allowedWidth=60;
      var ratio= allowedHeight/allowedWidth;
      var width=elm.width();
      var height=elm.height();
      if(width>height)
      {
        elm.width(allowedWidth);
        elm.Height(width*(allowedHeight/allowedWidth));
      }
      else      
    {
       elm.height(allowedHeight);
        elm.width(height*(allowedWidth/allowedHeight));
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it play nicely with JavaScript-disabled browsers? For example still display the image with broken ratio?

Comment: just minute fixing that problem too!!

Comment: And you probably mean if (width/height > 60/40), but I get your idea, thanks

Comment: yes create a ratio variable. do i need to write code for that??

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [jQuery image resize library](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/image-resize), and called it like:

```
$(function() {
  $( ".resizeme" ).aeImageResize({ height: 200, width: 250 });
  // Works with one parameter as well
  $( ".resizeme" ).aeImageResize({ width: 250 });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the wrong approach. Your comments on the other answers suggest that you aren't limiting the filesize/dimensions of uploaded photos. As you are expecting to resize the image client-side, the full image is fetched by the browser for each user in your top list.

What happens if someone uploads a 500KB jpeg? It's a possibility, a desktop-sized image at 100% quality could easily be that big. If you're showing 10 users, this could make each page view 5MB. I've seen plenty of sites go over bandwidth (and therefore be unavailable) due to serving original images.

What's your reason for not using a server-side resizer, such as timthumb?

Comment: Nobody is uploading any fotos to my server, I use fotos provided to me through REST by Facebook, Odnoklassniki.ru and 3 more social networks. So, really - I need something to resize images client-side, before displaying them in a list (this list is a list of players of my Facebook card game). Your concern of too big files is already handled by Facebook etc. upload guidelines/limits.

Answer (score 1):

If you set either the width or the height and leave the other one blank, it will resize and keep the ratio for you.

To do the clipping, maybe stick the `IMG` inside a `DIV` with dimensions of 60x40 and set `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: The problem with this suggestion is, that if someone has a foto with a really weird dimensions, like 300x40 and I set the height="40" only, then it won't make the width 300 fit into my wished width of 60.

Comment: @Alex I edited my answer to take care of clipping the image. If you want to fit any image into a rectangle of fixed dimensions and also maintain the aspect ratio, you are going to lose some of the image. Also, as adam says above, using original jpegs and resizing client-side could lead to enormous pages that require a lot of bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know if your picture is always too wide or too tall, this alone will not solve your problem, but you can always just set either width or height and your browser should scale the other dimension accordingly (preserving aspect ratio)

Comment: Thanks, but setting height=40 won't work for images of 300x40 - they still won't fit into my box 60x40